# Passing data to a jQueryUI dialog using PHP

Tags: php, forms, jquery-ui, dialog

Fairly new with jQuery itself. I am trying to use the jQueryUI dialog widget as a messaging service wherein users can click on a "Send Message" link and the dialog widget pops up. I was wondering how I can carry the username of the person receiving the message (from the php page) to the widget.

Here's a mock up of everything.

Here's a snippet of my html:

```
...
<tr>
 <td><img height="50px" width="50px" src="photos/1.png" /></td>
 <td><a href="#">username</a></td>
 <td>Real Name</td>
 <td><a href="#" id="opener">Send Message</a></td>
 <td><button>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
...
```

And here's the javascript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $dialog = $('#dialog')
  .dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  height: 350
 });
 $('#opener').click(function() {
  $dialog.dialog('open');
  return false;
 });
 $('#closedialog').click(function() {
  $dialog.dialog('close');
  return false;
 });
});
```

And here's what the dialog widget contains:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Send a message">
 <p>To: username</p>
   <div align="center">
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
   </div>
 <p align="right"><span style="text-align: right;"><button>Send message</button><button id="closedialog">Cancel</button></span></p>
</div>
```

Essentially, "username" will be replaced by data coming in from a MySQL database. I was thinking of a `<?php echo @_GET['username']; ?>` maybe a form or something but I'm kind of lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. PS: I know I did some things wrong in using the jQueryUI dialog widget, feel free to correct me on those as well.

Answer (score 0):

A standard php echo should work just fine.

```
<p>To: <?php echo $username;?></p>
```

You'll need to make sure the username variable is available in your modal.  If you're using a framework, check out how you pass data to a view.  Otherwise you can pass your variable to a function, set a constant, or do a number of other things.  If you tell me more about your PHP, I can help you.

Comment: I haven't actually gotten into the PHP part of the project. I was just kind of thinking how I'm going to do this part. Do I use this method of including the content of the dialog widget on the same page or should I get it from a different file using .load?

Comment: There's not much content...I don't think it would be a bad idea to include the dialog widget content on the same page.

Comment: Just shooting a question here. Since the example above (the snippet) will come from looping a php command to get data from MySQL, let's say the second row has the exact same data except the username is "username2", how would I go about passing that to the dialog widget content at the bottom? Are you getting where I'm going or I should just go back when I have the php figured out? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I think I got ya.  There's a list of users and you can send a message to each, right?  How about having a javascript function for each of the buttons that's something like this send_message('<?php echo $username;?>');  where send_message() is a javascript function that takes the username as a parameter.  Get me?

Comment: Now, I'm seeing a small light at the end of the tunnel (partly, because I'm not knowledgeable in JS). I see where you're trying to get me. I would need more help now though if I'm doing to go with your suggestion.

Comment: Get the usernames onto the page with php, then just pass them to a simple alert to gain the confidence of seeing javascript alert the username, and go from there.  You learn by experimentation.